# When should I repartition an RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, partitioning

I know that I can `repartition` an RDD to increase its partitions and use coalesce to decrease its partitions. I have two questions regarding this that I cannot completely understand after reading different resources.

Spark will use a sensible default (1 partition per block which is 64MB in first versions and now 128MB) when generating an RDD. But I also read that it is recommended to use 2 or 3 times the number of cores running the jobs. So here comes the question:

1. How many partitions should I use for a given file? For example, suppose I have a 10GB .parquet file, 3 executors with 2 cores and 3gb memory each.
   Should I repartition? How many partitions should I use? What is the better way to make that choice?
2. Are all data types (ie `.txt`, `.parquet`, etc..) repartitioned by default if no partitioning is provided?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, num of Partitions = num of Cores but you might want to oversubscribe. You'll find a lot of articles explaining why. Also, you can decrease the number of partitions with `repartition` as well.

Comment: If you are decreasing the number of partitions in this RDD, consider using coalesce, which can avoid performing a shuffle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Spark can run a single concurrent task for every partition of an RDD, up to the total number of cores in the cluster.*

For example :

```
val rdd= sc.textFile ("file.txt", 5)
```

The above line of code will create an RDD named textFile with 5 partitions.

Suppose that you have a cluster with 4 cores and assume that each partition needs to process for 5 minutes. In case of the above RDD with 5 partitions, 4 partition processes will run in parallel as there are 4 cores and the 5th partition process will process after 5 minutes when one of the 4 cores, is free.

The entire processing will be completed in 10 minutes and during the 5th partition process, the resources (remaining 3 cores) will remain idle.

> The best way to decide on the number of partitions in a `RDD` is to make the number of partitions equal to the number of cores in the cluster so that all the 
>   partitions will process in parallel and the resources will be utilized in an optimal way.

---

> Question : Are all data types (ie .txt, .parquet, etc..) repartitioned
>   by default if no partitioning is provided?

There will be default no of partitions for every rdd.
to check you can use `rdd.partitions.length` right after rdd created.

to use existing cluster resources in optimal way and to speed up,  we have to consider re-partitioning to ensure that all cores are utilized and all partitions have enough number of records which are uniformly distributed.

For better understanding, also have a look at https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-partitions.html

#### Note : There is no fixed formula for this. general convention most of them follow is

> (numOf executors * no of cores) * replicationfactor (which may be 2 or 3 times more )

Comment: I understand. But what happens if in your example the txt file size is 10gb and you have 4 cores in your cluster? It would make 2.5gb partition per core. Doesn't it affect the processing time/resources to have big partitions? Why not 8 partitions? Why not (10gb / 128Mb) partitions rouded down to a multiple of the number of cores?

Comment: yes in this case more number of partitions need but it will work like afore-mentioned approach. since its not single liner answer... I'd recommend you to  see [top-5-mistakes-to-avoid-when-writing-apache-spark-applications](https://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/top-5-mistakes-to-avoid-when-writing-apache-spark-applications) & [Tuning Resource Allocation](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/)

Comment: please note that there is no fixed formula for this. general convention most of them follow is (numOf executors * no of cores) * replicationfactor(which may be 2 or 3 times more )